# Magento - Where do I go to edit file that outputs the sitemap?

Tags: magento, sitemap, magento-1.5

I would like to update the template that generates the google sitemap in Magento 1.5.

Reason being, Magento is using the URLKey (e.g. /my-jacket.html) and not the full URL with category (e.g. /outerwear/jackets/my-jacket.html).

I'm doing this in another place on the site (an .html sitemap) and it works great. When looping through products inside a category...

```
// get the categories for this product
$_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)->getCategoryIds();                                                                              
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[0]);

// build the URL path   
$url = Mage::getUrl($_category->getUrlPath()).basename($_product->getUrlKey());     

// only problem is this will be /category/category2.html/my-jacket.html
// so strip the .html and put it on the end
$url = str_replace(".html","" ,$url) . '.html';
```

It's ugly but works. Anyway, I want to do the same to the google sitemap that gets generated, but after much searching for where it is generated, I can't find it. Anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that there's no simple template to edit.  The XML generating happens inside of a model, specifically: `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap::generateXml()`.